# Is there way to get only "valid" locations from the Azure locations REST API?

Tags: azure, azure-rest-api

When calling the Azure locations REST API `https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/locations?api-version=2020-01-01` it returns around 65 locations (also called regions).

This is the official API documentation **including an example response**:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/resources/subscriptions/listlocations

If I then call the [Quota List API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/reserved-vm-instances/quota/list) for all these locations, for some locations I get `400 Bad Request` errors. (For around 20 locations out of those 65.)

Now, I figured out that I can filter the location list by `"regionType": "Physical"` and it reduces the number of the "Bad Request" responses. But I still have locations in the list that are not available in my Azure subscription. For example "westus3" is one of those regions that I get from the API but it looks like it's not availavle in my subscription. I double checked it in the Azure Portal "Usage + quotas" and westus3 (West US 3) is not available:
[image]

This is how westus3 looks like in the location API response (notice, it's physical and recommended):

```json
    {
      "id": "/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/locations/westus3",
      "name": "westus3",
      "displayName": "West US 3",
      "regionalDisplayName": "(US) West US 3",
      "metadata": {
        "regionType": "Physical",
        "regionCategory": "Recommended",
        "geographyGroup": "US",
        "longitude": "-112.074036",
        "latitude": "33.448376",
        "physicalLocation": "Phoenix",
        "pairedRegion": [
          {
            "name": "eastus",
            "id": "/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/locations/eastus"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
```

Since I preiodically check all quotas from all locations I am getting these 400 errors all the time. Is there  way to get only "valid" locations for a certain subscription from the locations REST API?

---

EDIT

The problematic call is:

```
GET https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/providers/Microsoft.Capacity/resourceProviders/Microsoft.Compute/locations/westus3/serviceLimits?api-version=2020-10-25
Authorization: Bearer XXX
```

The 400 response is:

```json
{
  "error": {
    "code": "NoRegisteredProviderFound",
    "message": "No registered resource provider found for location 'westus3' and API version '2020-06-01' for type 'locations/usages'. The supported api-versions are '2015-05-01-preview, 2015-06-15, 2016-03-30, 2016-04-30-preview, 2016-08-30, 2017-03-30, 2017-12-01, 2018-04-01, 2018-06-01, 2018-10-01, 2019-03-01, 2019-07-01, 2019-12-01, 2020-06-01, 2020-12-01, 2021-03-01'. The supported locations are 'eastus, eastus2, westus, centralus, northcentralus, southcentralus, northeurope, westeurope, eastasia, southeastasia, japaneast, japanwest, australiaeast, australiasoutheast, australiacentral, brazilsouth, southindia, centralindia, westindia, canadacentral, canadaeast, westus2, westcentralus, uksouth, ukwest, koreacentral, koreasouth, francecentral, southafricanorth, uaenorth, switzerlandnorth, germanywestcentral, norwayeast, jioindiawest'."
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you edit your question and include the error details for the 400 (Bad Request) error you're getting?

Comment: Updated. Notice, it's not the Quota Update API, it's the Quote List API. I corrected it. Sorry for my mistake.